# How to fix pass two parameters in dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 dropdownlist in View but I don't know how to get id for script work, please help me. tks in thanks in advance

this is my controller for IndexList to create a list

```js
public ActionResult IndexList() {
  ViewBag.falcuty_id = new SelectList(db.faculties, "faculty_id",
    "faculty_name");
  ViewBag.linktoYearId = GetYears();
  return View();
}
```

this is my dropdownlist controller to create a controller to choose year

```js
private SelectList GetYears() {
  int CurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

  for (int i = 2017; i <= CurrentYear; i++) {
    ddlYears.Add(new SelectListItem {
      Text = i.ToString(),
      Value = i.ToString()
    });
  }
  return new SelectList(ddlYears, "Value", "Text");
}
```

This is method need to pass parameter. This method will query and count the number of content by faculty ID and date_post

```js
public ActionResult List(int date,string date) {
  int count = (db.contents.Where(x => x.date_post.Value.Year == date && x.faculty_id == "IT")).Count();

  Session["count"] = count;
  return RedirectToAction("IndexList", "contents");
}
```

and my View in index. The script doesn't work

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="row" style="border:solid; border-width:thin; padding:20px; height:400px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div class="row">

                @Html.DropDownList("falcuty_id", null, new   { @onChange = "selectFaculty(this)" })

                <div class="col-lg-6" align="left">
                    @Html.DropDownList("linktoYearId", null, "---Select year---",new {
                   @id = "ddlYears",
                   @onChange = "SelectedValue(this)",
                   @class = "form-control",
                   @style = "width:200px"
               })
                    <h1>@Session["count"]</h1>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
   function SelectedValue(ddlObject) {
      var selectedValue = ddlObject.value;
    }
   function selectFaculty(falObject1) {
     var selectedValue = falObject1.value;
     window.location.href = '@Url.Action("List","contents")?date=' + parseInt(selectedValue.ddlObject.value) + '?faculty=' + falObject1.value;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: There is only one dropdown list in the code above, is  there meant to be two? Is your objective to pass the value to the controller?

Comment: first dropdownlist is a dropdownlist for faculty_id and the second dropdownlist for linktoYearId and I need to pass two parameters of it to controller

Comment: If the values you are wanting are from both dropdowns, you can either just call the controller with a view model that has them parameters (the ones in the dropdown) OR get rid of the html.beginform and use jquery to get their values and pass them to he controller. Out of both I personally would do the second